# delete duplicate values in a row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas data frame:

```
>>df_freq = pd.DataFrame([["Z11", "Z11", "X11"], ["Y11","",""], ["Z11","Z11",""]], columns=list('ABC'))

>>df_freq
    A   B   C
0   Z11 Z11 X11
1   Y11     
2   Z11 Z11
```

I want to make sure each row has unique values only. Therefore it should become like this: Removed values can be replaced with zero or empty

```
    A   B   C
0   Z11 0   X11
1   Y11     
2   Z11 0
```

My data frame is big with hundreds of columns and thousands of rows. The goal is to count the unique values in that data frame. I do that by using converting data frame to matrix and applying

```
>>np.unique(mat.astype(str), return_counts=True)
```

But in certain row(s) the same value occurs and I want to remove that before applying np.unique() method. I want to keep unique values in each row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a combination of `astype(bool)` and `duplicated`

```
mask = df_freq.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, 1) & df_freq.astype(bool)

df_freq.mask(mask, 0)

     A  B    C
0  Z11  0  X11
1  Y11        
2  Z11  0
```

Comment: Could you convert it to a in-situ change based one? Would like to time it.

Comment: Hey piR, what's the reason for  `df_freq.astype(bool)`? The code seems to work fine without it.

Comment: @moondra OP had blanks `''` in the dataframe, and multiple ones.  I didn't want to put zeros when the second, third, etc blanks showed up.  So, I know that `''` evaluates as `False` therefore I take `df_freq.astype(bool)` to create a mask where things are not blank.  That in conjunction with when there are duplicates allow me to accurately place the zeros.  Otherwise, I'd end up with an extra zero in `df_freq.loc[1, 'C']`

Comment: Ah! You're right. I didn't even catch that extra `0` at `df_freq.loc[1, 'C']`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized NumPy approach -

```
def reset_rowwise_dups(df):
    n = df.shape[0]
    row_idx = np.arange(n)[:,None]

    a = df_freq.values
    idx = np.argsort(a,1)
    sorted_a = a[row_idx, idx]
    idx_reversed = idx.argsort(1)
    sorted_a_dupmask = sorted_a[:,1:] == sorted_a[:,:-1]
    dup_mask = np.column_stack((np.zeros(n,dtype=bool), sorted_a_dupmask))
    final_mask = dup_mask[row_idx, idx_reversed] & (a != '' )
    a[final_mask] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [80]: df_freq
Out[80]: 
     A    B    C    D
0  Z11  Z11  X11  Z11
1  Y11            Y11
2  Z11  Z11       X11

In [81]: reset_rowwise_dups(df_freq)

In [82]: df_freq
Out[82]: 
     A  B    C    D
0  Z11  0  X11    0
1  Y11            0
2  Z11  0       X11
```

**Runtime test**

```
# Proposed earlier in this post
def reset_rowwise_dups(df):
    n = df.shape[0]
    row_idx = np.arange(n)[:,None]

    a = df.values
    idx = np.argsort(a,1)
    sorted_a = a[row_idx, idx]
    idx_reversed = idx.argsort(1)
    sorted_a_dupmask = sorted_a[:,1:] == sorted_a[:,:-1]
    dup_mask = np.column_stack((np.zeros(n,dtype=bool), sorted_a_dupmask))
    final_mask = dup_mask[row_idx, idx_reversed] & (a != '' )
    a[final_mask] = 0

# @piRSquared's soln using pandas apply
def apply_based(df):
    mask = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, 1) & df.astype(bool)
    return df.mask(mask, 0)
```

Timings -

```
In [151]: df_freq = pd.DataFrame([["Z11", "Z11", "X11", "Z11"], \
     ...:  ["Y11","","", "Y11"],["Z11","Z11","","X11"]], columns=list('ABCD'))

In [152]: df_freq
Out[152]: 
     A    B    C    D
0  Z11  Z11  X11  Z11
1  Y11            Y11
2  Z11  Z11       X11

In [153]: df = pd.concat([df_freq]*10000,axis=0)

In [154]: df.index = range(df.shape[0])

In [155]: %timeit apply_based(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.35 s per loop

In [156]: %timeit reset_rowwise_dups(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Sorry was busy :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def replaceDuplicateData(nestedList):
    for row in range(len(nestedList)):
        uniqueDataRow = []
        for col in range(len(nestedList[row])):
            if nestedList[row][col] not in uniqueDataRow:
                uniqueDataRow.append(nestedList[row][col])
            else:
                nestedList[row][col] = 0
    return nestedList

nestedList = [["Z11", "Z11", "X11"], ["Y11","",""], ["Z11","Z11",""]]
print (replaceDuplicateData(nestedList))
```

Basically you can use that function above to remove duplication in your matrix.